# How to add some loading message in angularjs every route changes

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

Im new to angularjs and Im currently learning on angular's ng-route. I already done on it but what I want to achieve is to display first the loading message before displaying the content of the address of the route.
What's happening on my code right now is like this:

*1.* Click the `home` link
*2.* Display the loading message on the current page before successfully loading the content of the `home` link

That's how my code works, and I don't want it that way.
What I want to happen is something like this:

*1.* Click the `home` link
*2.* Current page will be hidden and display the loading message before displaying the content of the `home` link

I hope you understand. By the way here's my code:

**index.html**

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainController">

  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> main</a>
  <a href="#home"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> home</a>

   <!-- start views -->

  <div ng-view></div>

</body>
```

**script.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
    app.config(function($routeProvider){

      $routeProvider
          .when('/',{
               templateUrl: 'main.html',
               controller: 'mainController',
               resolve:{
                   delay: function($q, $timeout){
                        var delay = $q.defer();
                        $timeout(delay.resolve, 1000);
                        return delay.promise;
                    }
               }
           })
           .when('/home',{
               templateUrl: 'home.html',
               controller: 'homeController',
               resolve:{
                   delay: function($q, $timeout){
                        var delay = $q.defer();
                        $timeout(delay.resolve, 1000);
                        return delay.promise;
                    }
               }
           })
           .otherwise({
                 redirectTo: '/'
           });

    });


     app.controller('mainController', function($scope){
          $scope.message = "...";
     });

      app.controller('homeController', function($scope){
          $scope.message = "...";
     });



      app.directive('showDuringResolve', function($rootScope) {

      return {
         link: function(scope, element) {

              element.addClass('ng-hide');

             var unregister = $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {
                element.removeClass('ng-hide');
            });

             $scope.$on('$destroy', unregister);
          }
       };
     });
```

**main.html**

```
    <h1>Main Page</h1>

     <div show-during-resolve class="alert alert-info">
      <strong>Loading.</strong>
      Please hold.
   </div>
```

**home.html**

```
    <h1>Home Page</h1>

     <div show-during-resolve class="alert alert-info">
      <strong>Loading.</strong>
      Please hold.
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve the desired behavior with few modification in your code.

Add the loader text in your index.html file and show/hide the ng-view and loading text based on the rootScope variable statechange

```
<div ng-view ng-show="statechange"></div>
  <div ng-show="!statechange" show-during-resolve class="alert alert-info">
      <strong>Loading.</strong>
      Please hold.</div>
```

in your directive make the following change.

```
 app.directive('showDuringResolve', function($rootScope) {

      return {
         link: function(scope, element) {

              element.addClass('ng-hide');
              $rootScope.statechange =  true;

             var unregister = $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {
                element.removeClass('ng-hide');
                   $rootScope.statechange =  false;
            });

            scope.$on('$destroy', unregister);
          }
       };
     });
```

Plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/RISv2lvxwf75nuVfWLgA?p=preview

Comment: that's exactly what I want sir! Thanks a lot. btw, im from philippines!

Comment: @TrishSiquian Welcome :) Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable in each controller like `dataReady`, so for example in your home page, you can do something like:

html:

```
<div ng-show="dataReady">
  <h1>Home Page</h1>

     <div show-during-resolve class="alert alert-info">
      <strong>Loading.</strong>
      Please hold.
   </div>
</div>

<div ng-show="!dataReady">
  <h1> Loading ...</h1>
</div>
```

js:

```
app.controller('homeController', function($scope){
     $scope.message = "...";
     // After all the logic
     $scope.dataReady = true;

});
```

And repeat the same idea for all the pages that you need.

Comment: Thanks by the way!

Answer (score 0):

By default set the loader to be hide

```
<strong class="loader" id="loader">Loading....</strong>

.loader{
   display: none;
}
.loader-show{
   display: inline-block;
}
```

When request made to get data, show the loader by adding `loader-show` class. On successful completion of request, hide loader by removing `loader-show` class.
That is,

```
       resolve:{
           delay: function($q, $timeout){
                var loader = document.getElementById('loader');
                loader.addClass('loader-show'); // when request is going to made
                var delay = $q.defer();
                $timeout(delay.resolve, 1000);
                loader.removeClass('loader-show'); // when request ends
                return delay.promise;
            }
       }
```